# python: Parametered 2 dimentional list's size whether it meets my requirement or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, methods

I wanted to check the passed two dimensional list meets my requirement.

```
def foo(twoDList):
 if len(twoDList) == 2:
   if len(twoDList[]) == 3:
     print("true")
```

Then while using the method:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
foo(a)
```

Should have be true! How can I fix foo() for

len(twoDList) == 2 and all(len(sublist) == 3 for sublist in twoDList)

Comment: Do you mean `len(twoDList) == 2 and all(len(sublist) == 3 for sublist in twoDList)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len(twoDList[])` gives me a syntax error, because you have to pass an index between the square brackets.

I assume you want each sublist have exactly three elements :

```
def foo(twoDList):
    if len(twoDList) == 2:
        if all(len(sublist) == 3 for sublist in twoDList):
            print("true")
```

If you want to raise an error if twoDList doesn't meet the requirements, then use `assert` keyword :

```
def foo(twoDList):
    assert(len(twoDList) == 2 and all(len(sublist) == 3 for sublist in twoDList))
    print("true")
```

Comment: Right, thank you!

Comment: I have exactly the same code, nice! Up to the name of the variables.